# Install Chromium (not Google Chrome) on Linux

Tags: linux, chromium

I downloaded a rar archive from `https://download-chromium.appspot.com/` but I can't seem to install it properly, or even get it to work. I had no problem on Windows but on Linux I do not have a clue what is wrong.

I also tried adding the repository with `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chromium-daily/stable` but this is for Chrome.

My question is, how to install Chromium on Linux?

Comment: What Linux are you using? That ppa is for Ubuntu only.

Comment: Also, what makes you think the PPA is for `chrome`? It seems to be for `chromium`.

Comment: What system? Linux is just a kernel, there is no set way of installing things.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:a-v-shkop/chromium
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

Or [here](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/chromium-browser/)

Comment: is this the dev build?

Comment: [It's the stable](https://launchpad.net/~a-v-shkop/+archive/chromium), but unofficial.

Answer (score 1):

The details depend on the Linux distribution you are using but most should have official chromium packages:

- Debian/Ubuntu (and all its variants)/LMDE

  The package is in the main repository, you should be able to install with

  ```
  sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
  ```
- Fedora ([source](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Chromium)) (and I would guess RHEL and CentOS)

  Download the repo file from from http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/spot/chromium-stable/fedora-chromium-stable.repo and drop it in `/etc/yum.repos.d` as root user.

  Use PackageKit or run the following command

  ```
  sudo yum install chromium -y
  ```
- Arch (as root)

  Again, the package is in the main repositories, install it with

  ```
  packman -S chromium
  ```

  For all other distributions, follow the [instructions](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxBuildInstructions) on the `chromium` project's webpage.

Comment: +1 for not assuming OP uses ubuntu.